# Add "active" class to Top Menu Category Item if Child is Current

Tags: magento-1.9, category, menu, navigation

Within **topmenu.phtml** I am removing the default  so that I can easier create a custom menu with my own classes (for implementation into Foundation CSS Framework using [Top Bar](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/topbar.html)).

How would I add a custom "active" class to the parent `<li>` if a child / descendent category of the selected is currently active?

I'm using the following code to generate the menu:

```
<ul>
  <?php
       $obj = new Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation();
       $storeCategories = $obj->getStoreCategories();
       Mage::registry('current_category') ? $currentCategoryId = Mage::registry('current_category')->getId() : $currentCategoryId='';
       foreach ($storeCategories as $_category):
   ?>
           <li class="<!--active class here if child is current -->">
               <a href="#"><?php echo $_category->getName(); ?></a>
               <?php $categoryChildren = $_category->getChildren(); ?>
               <?php if($categoryChildren->count()) : ?>
                   <ul class="dropdown">
                       <?php foreach($categoryChildren as $_categoryChild) : ?>
                           <?php $_categoryChildModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_categoryChild->getId());?>
                           <?php $categoryGrandchildren=$_categoryChild->getChildren(); ?>
                           <li>
                               <?php
                                   $currentCategoryId===$_categoryChild->getId() ? $bold="style=\"font-weight:bold\"" : $bold='';
                                   echo '&emsp;' . '<a href="' . $_categoryChildModel->getUrl() . '"' . $bold . '>' .  $_categoryChild->getName() . '</a>';
                               ?>
                           </li>
                           <?php if($categoryGrandchildren->count()) : ?>
                               <?php foreach($categoryGrandchildren as $_categoryGrandchild) : ?>
                                   <?php $_categoryGrandchildModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_categoryGrandchild->getId());?>
                                   <li>
                                       <?php
                                           $currentCategoryId===$_categoryChild->getId() ? $bold="style=\"font-weight:bold\"" : $bold='';
                                           echo '&emsp;&emsp;' . '<a href="' . $_categoryGrandchildModel->getUrl() . '"' . $bold . '>' .  $_categoryGrandchild->getName() . '(' . $_categoryGrandchildModel->getProductCount() . ')</a>';
                                       ?>
                                   </li>
                               <?php endforeach; ?>
                           <?php endif; ?>
                       <?php endforeach; ?>
                   </ul>
               <?php endif; ?>
           </li>
       <?php endforeach ?>

   </ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
<li class="<!--active class here if child is current -->">
```

To

```
<li<?php echo in_array($_category->getId(), Mage::registry('current_category')->getPathIds()) ? ' class="custom-active-class"' : '' ?>>
```

EDIT:
You need to add the category id to the cache key to make it work. Otherwise this solution wouldn't work with block caching enabled.

Comment: guys, please comment whats wrong with the answer when you vote it down. The answer fully answers the main question, so I don't see a reason to minus it

Comment: Your solution wouldn't work with block cache, Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation is cached without an expiration time.

"If cache_lifetime is equal to false, it means that the cache will never expire." => http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/block_cache_and_html_ouput

Comment: @RobM84, if you add ID of current category to cache key of the block, it will work perfectly

Comment: Sure this would work, I added it to your answer.

Comment: @RobM84, thank you

Comment: @RobM84, will appreciate voting up this comment since it is totally correct

Comment: I've upvoted your answer, thanks.  However I should have been more clear:  I should have placed more emphasis on adding the class if any DESCENDANT is selected of the current navigation item- whether it's a child, grandchild, etc.  Is this possible?

Comment: @joe, I've made the changes for selecting parent of current category

Comment: @alex_b thank you so much for helping me, this is exactly what I was looking for.  As a side note, I went ahead and created a separate version with a "Topmenu.php" as a custom module override.  :)

Comment: Good point. Glad to help :)

Comment: @alex_b unfortunately, one more thing- with your method the "active" class gets stuck / cached on all pages that are not category pages if you view a category page first after flushing.  Works as intended when switching to other category pages.   What could cause this?

Comment: Have you added category_id to cache key of the block?